# Failed lookup for key [category] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {}, {},

Tags: python, django, templatetags, mptt

I'm getting this error Failed lookup for key `[category]` in `[{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {}, {}, ....]`
in my application I have category and subcategory which repeated too much in my view for every function and  for child or subcategory I used `pip install django-mptt` but it was Ok and worked will. So I decided to use custom template tags instead but right now I'm facing with this error

For more info you can take a look to my code.
myapptags.py

```
from django import template
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.urls import reverse

from mysite import settings
from order.models import ShopCard
from product.models import Category

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def categorylist():
    return Category.objects.all()
```

code for views.py

```
import json 
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

from . models import Settings, ContactMessage, FAQ
from product.models import Category, Comment, Images, Product, Variants
from . forms import ContactForm, SearchForm
from product.forms import CommentForm


def index(request):
    setting = Settings.objects.get(pk=1)
    # category = Category.objects.all()
    products_slider = Product.objects.all().order_by('id')[:4] #first 4 product 
    products_latest = Product.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:4] # latest
    products_picked = Product.objects.all().order_by('?')[:4] # random 

    page = "index"

    context = {
        'setting': setting,
        'page': page,
        # 'category': category,
        'products_slider': products_slider,
        'products_latest': products_latest,
        'products_picked': products_picked,
    }
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

side bar which contain my category and it's children

```
                    {% load myapptags %}
                    {% categorylist as category %}
                    {% load mptt_tags %}
                    <ul class="category-list">
                        {% recursetree category %}
                            <li class="dropdown side-dropdown">
                                <a href="{% url 'home:category-product' node.id node.slug %}" class="dropdown-toggle" {% if not node.is_leaf_node %} data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true" {% endif %} >
                                    {{ node.title }} {% if not node.is_leaf_node %} <i class="fa fa-angle-right"> {% endif %}</i>
                                </a>
                                <div class="custom-menu">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-4">
                                            {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                                                <ul class="list-links">
                                                    <li>
                                                        <!-- <h3 class="list-links-title">Sub Categories</h3></li> -->
                                                        <hr>
                                                    <li><a href="#">{{ children }}</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            {% endif %}
                                            <hr class="hidden-md hidden-lg">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- <div class="row hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <hr>
                                            <a class="banner banner-1" href="#">
                                            <img src="{{ node.image.url }}" style="{ width: 50%; height: 100px;}" alt="">
                                                <div class="banner-caption text-center">
                                                    <h2 class="white-color">NEW COLLECTION</h2>
                                                    <h3 class="white-color font-weak">HOT DEAL</h3>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> -->
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        {% endrecursetree %}
                    </ul>
```

Thanks in advance for your nice answers

Answer (score 0):

Edit your views.py

```
def index(request):
setting = Settings.objects.get(pk=1)
category = Category.objects.all()
products_slider = Product.objects.all().order_by('id')[:4] #first 4 product 
products_latest = Product.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:4] # latest
products_picked = Product.objects.all().order_by('?')[:4] # random 

page = "index"

context = {
    'setting': setting, 
    'category': category,
    'page': page, 
    'category': category,
    'products_slider': products_slider,
    'products_latest': products_latest,
    'products_picked': products_picked,
}
return render(request,'index.html',context)
```